# Обновление контрола формы

Tags: c#, winforms

На форме есть TreeView. Необходимо обновить всё содержимое контрола (требуется только Nodes, но нет их сеттера), но так не работает:

```
public void SetTreeView(TreeView new_tree_view)
{
    TV_branches = new_tree_view;
}
```

Пробовал и TV_branches.Update() - без разницы. Как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Возможно нужно вызвать ```Invalidate()```?

Comment: Я уже много раз высказывался: за бездумное применение методов `Update`, `Invalidate`, `Refresh` нужно отлучать от профессии. Почему никто не читает документацию по этим (и другим) методам? Лепят их вызовы куда попало...

Answer (score 2):

`TreeView` - это GUI-контрол. Мало просто присвоить ссылке новый экземпляр, нужно настроить его правильно, а предыдущий экземпляр удалить.

В примере показано, что нужно новый контрол обязательно поместить на форму, для чего задано `Parent = this`, а старый контрол удалить, для чего вызван `TV_branches.Dispose();`.

Компилируем, запускаем приложение, кликаем по форме - лицезреем изменение.

Естественно, **все** свойства нового контрола (местоположение, докинг, цвета и т. п.) должны совпадать со старым. В моём примере `Dock` отличается, чтобы было сразу видно появление нового тривью и исчезновение старого. Сложно? Да. Очевидно, вам совсем не это нужно.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    TreeView TV_branches;
    public Form1()
    {
        TV_branches = new TreeView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Left };
        TV_branches.Nodes.Add("1");
        TV_branches.Nodes.Add("2");

        this.Click += Form1_Click;
    }

    private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var treeView = new TreeView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Right };
        treeView.Nodes.Add("3");
        treeView.Nodes.Add("4");
        SetTreeView(treeView);
    }

    public void SetTreeView(TreeView new_tree_view)
    {
        TV_branches.Dispose();
        TV_branches = new_tree_view;
    }
}
```

---

Просто удалите все старые узлы вызовом метода `Clear()`. После чего добавьте новые узлы с помощью `AddRange`.

```
private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var nodes = new TreeNode[]
    {
        new TreeNode("3"),
        new TreeNode("4")
    };
    SetTreeView(nodes);
}

public void SetTreeView(TreeNode[] nodes)
{
    TV_branches.Nodes.Clear();
    TV_branches.Nodes.AddRange(nodes);
}
```